# Defining commands to select different package fonts

Tags: fonts, metafont

I would like to have two different font styles in my document that are, unfortunately called by the same command.

I would like to have `\mathscr{}` as called by the package `eucal` with the `mathscr` option.  Additionally, it would be very helpful to have the `\mathscr{}` as called by the package `mathrsfs`.

Is there a way to define commands at the beginning of my document so I only need to use one of these packages while have the font effect from the other package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathrsfs}{rsfs}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}

\begin{document}

$\mathcal{ABC}\mathscr{ABC}\mathrsfs{ABC}$

\end{document}
```